# Reaching memory limit launching a task

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a long task to run under my App Engine application with a lot of datastore to compute. It worked well with a small amount of data, but since yesterday, I'm suddenly getting more than a million datastore entries to compute per day. After a while running the task (around 2 minutes), it fails with a 202 exit code (HTTP error 500). I really cannot deal with this issue. It is pretty much undocumented. The only information I was able to find is that it probably means that my app is running out of memory.

The task is simple. Each entry in the datastore contains a non-unique string identifier and a long number. The task sums the numbers and stores the identifiers into a set.

My budget is really low since my app is entirely free and without ads. I would like to prevent the app cost to soar. I would like to find a cheap and simple solution to this issue.

Edit:
I read Objectify documentation thoroughly tonight, and I found that [the session cache](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BasicOperations#The_Session_Cache) (which ensures entities references consistency) can consume a lot of memory and should be cleared regularly when performing a lot of requests (which is my case). Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to stay within the free quota but it will require a little extra work.

In your case you should split this operation into smaller batches ( ej process 1000 entities per batch) and queue those smaller tasks to run sequentially during off hours. That should save you form the memory issue and allow you to scale beyond your current entity amount.

Comment: Thank you ! How would you do that ? Would you store the last computed entity id in the datastore and start again from it the next time the task is performed ? Is it a good idea ? With 1000 entities per batch, I would need to run my task ~1000 times per day to complete.